# loading cl+ssl using clisp/asdf under windows 7

Tags: windows, common-lisp, clisp, asdf

I am trying to load up "cl+ssl" via

```
(asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :cl+ssl)
```

resulting in

```
Component :TRIVIAL-GARBAGE not found, required by #<SYSTEM "cl+ssl">
```

is this problem known to anybody and if yes/no how can  I fix this, or how can I approach to fix it?

Comment: You have to first install trivial-garbage system in a place, where ASDF can find it. Quicklisp can do all that for you

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to do the old-style, cumbersome `ASDF:OOS`, any more.  ASDF finally has the simple: `(asdf:load-system :cl+ssl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asdf:load-op` doesn't automatically install dependencies for you (though I think it does automatically load them if you've already got them installed).

Really, the best way of handling this is by using [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).

If you don't want to do that, you can probably install `trivial-garbage` via `asdf-install`, or manually install it from the [source](https://github.com/trivial-garbage/trivial-garbage).